# OrientDB activity feed query with TRAVERSE

Tags: javascript, sql, orientdb

im new on orientDB, i start to use this database with the graph mode and i want to create a query to get the activity feed of a specific user. usually in the nosql databases i duplicate a key of any new activity in the activity node of each follower. but i see that in the graph database is possible to avoid this process because i can get any activity with the TRAVERSE method. i have a series of differents vertex linked by a series of different EDGES. my graph is this

[image]

any user is a vertex that can follow another user, can create new events and can left a comment to other events. any edge that start from a user is a child class of the parent `"UserEdgeActivity"`, my question is that, how can i get the activities of users who i follow? 
any EDGE have three properties `created: datetime, in: LINK, out: LINK`

to retrieve all edge activites by my followings i use this query

```
SELECT FROM(TRAVERSE outE("UserEdgeActivity") FROM (SELECT FROM OUser WHERE name="admin")) WHERE $depth > 0 AND out!=#5:5 AND in!=#5:5 ORDER BY created DESC
```

Unfortunately, the query returns a null result, but the user "admin" follow different users that did different activities.
my goal is to retrive all follow, event or comment actions that my following contact had make ordered by date, but excluding incoming activities towards the user "admin" or coming out from him.
i think that this is possible with the traverse method. what is the exact query to do this?

UPDATE:

solved with this query

```
SELECT FROM(TRAVERSE out("NewFollow"), outE("UserEdgeActivity") FROM (SELECT FROM OUser WHERE name=? LIMIT 1) WHILE $depth < 3) WHERE $depth > 0 AND out.name!=? AND (in["@class"]!="OUser" OR in.name!=?)AND @class!="OUser" AND (@class!="NewComment" OR (@class="NewComment" AND in.out("NewCommentToEvent")[0].in("NewEvent")[0]["name"]!=?)) ORDER BY created DESC
```

Comment: Hi, which version are you using?

Comment: Can you substitute the picture with another one identic but insted of the rid with the label? Thx in advance

And what should be the expected result?

Comment: hi michela, i solved my problem with the last query. you can see in my updated post. the expected result is that i want to retrive all activity of the people that i follow excluding all activities towards me. now i can do this but i have another question. at moment i can retrive all edges activity. there are a method to retrive a edge joined with a vertex? for example: if i have a "NewFollow" edge can i join this with the following and follower vertexes?